# Example on how to wire up durable function dependency injection

Tags: function, azure, logging, code-injection

Having successfully created and run a simple Azure Durable Function in Visual Studio 2017, I want to introduce logging.

The Visual Studio project template generates the static HttpStart class with a
Run method containing an optional parameter of type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.

I have no idea how to hook up dependency injection into a durable function project. Can anyone point me to an example on how to achieve this?

It looks to me like I will need some class, inside which I will need to use the  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggingFactory.CreateLogger() method.

I imagine that this logic will need to be within a container class that is hooked into the run time pipeline using HostBuilder in some way (similar to using WebHostBuilder in static main method).

Thank you

Comment: Are you using azure function v1 or v2 ? checks this post: https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/dependency-injection-for-azure-functions/. And here is a project that deal with azure function v2 and DI: https://github.com/BorisWilhelms/azure-function-dependency-injection

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your pointers.  I was able to get this going using code from the examples you indicated.
Sorry about the delay, the CPU fan died on the pc that contained only code I had for the 'home' project.

Comment: No worries, it hapens sometimes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thomas pointed me to examples I used to extract code that allows dependency injection to work when writing a durable function project:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using tmetadastoreFnApp;
using Willezone.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ILogger = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger;
using LogLevel = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace tmetadastoreFnApp
{
    internal class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder) =>
            builder.AddDependencyInjection(ConfigureServices);

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
            services.AddLogging((builder) => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            loggerFactory.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { CaptureMessageTemplates = true, CaptureMessageProperties = true });

            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            LogManager.LoadConfiguration(Directory.GetParent(dir) + "\\nlog.config");

        }
    }
}
```